# Plant identification — Phuket, Thailand

Tags: botany, species-identification

Found in Phuket, Thailand. White flower, five petals, 5 stamens. Strings of flowers hanging down from red stems. Buds white, tear-drop shape.[image][image]

RHA, Here are the leaves. The flowers hang from a bush about 6 foot (2 metres Tall)

Bli, thanks, but not honeysuckle. No scent.

[image: Leaves of unidentified plant]

Comment: Nice pictures of the flowers! Do these flowers hang from a tree? Any idea what the leaves look like?

Comment: This vaguely reminds me of Lonicera, but is clearly not the species I know.

Answer (score 11):

This is *Clerodendrum schmitii* similar to *C. wallichii* (Bridal Veil). It is commonly called Chains of Glory and is native to Thailand.

It belongs to Verbenaceae family.

> Chains of Glory is a shrub to small tree, multi-stemmed, with hanging branches. Each winter it grows long, pendent, dark red racemes, 1.5 ft long, of delicate white flowers. The cascading white fragrant flowers are held in loose hanging clusters, similar to Bridal Veil. The white flowers on long dark red flower stalks look very attractive against the dark green leaves. Chains of Glory is native to Thailand.

*(from [flowersofindia](https://www.flowersofindia.net/catalog/slides/Chains%20of%20Glory.html))*

> The genus is native  to tropical and warm temperate regions of the world, with most of the species occurring in tropical Africa and southern Asia, but with a few in the tropical Americas and northern Australasia, and a few extending north into the temperate zone in eastern Asia.

*(from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clerodendrum))*

**Picture reference:**

[image]  *Chains of Glory* $^1$

[image] *Bridal Veil* $^2$

$^1$ *(Source: [tuoitre.vn](http://tuoitre.vn/tin/kinh-te/20160116/ngoc-minh-chau-la-la-cho-tet/1039384.html))*

$^2$ *(Source: [Cebuano wiki](https://ceb.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clerodendrum_wallichii))*

Comment: Excellent find! It would be nice to include a picture or at least a link to a picture; your wikipedia only points to the genus.

Comment: @RHA Updated the answer.